# Dropbox datastore API sync strategy: how to handle unlink and link again?

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api, datastore

I played with the Dropbox Datastore APIs, it's very simple and convenient. I figured out the process after the account being linked. But I'm having trouble designing the sync strategy in a very common situation after unlink:

Say device **A** and **B** are linked to Dropbox, and have all data synced for the first time. Later device **A** is unlinked. Now there are two copies of the data, and the Dropbox Datastore is in sync with **B**. Then several insert, delete, update operations are performed on **A** and **B** separately. After **A** linked to Dropbox again, how should I handle the conflicts?

This is an Android app. It has a local SQLite database. After Dropbox linked, the SQLite database and dropbox datastore work together in a mirroring way. And unlink will remove the dropbox part, but keep the local SQLite.

(Two solutions I can think of:

1. Do not use local mirrored database, after unlink, all data are gone, and user has to get data back by relink. I think iCould is doing something like this.
2. Unlink remove the app on the Dropbox, only keep the local SQLite store.
3. Bookkeeping all the local changes and timestamps, and on relink, walkthrough all the data, and resolve conflicts. This can be tricky, and add another level of complexity to the app.)

Any one familiar with Dropbox datastore APIs can leave some comments? Thanks.

**Update:**

Now I'm using two id columns in my local SQLite: an integer _id column is only for Android content provider & cursor adapter, I keep it internal; another one is string type generated by random UUID, this is actually the primary id column, and I use it for query, foreign key reference to other tables. This makes data consistency a lot easier. Dropbox datastore id column is my local UUID string column. For the situation of unlink, the local db still keeps the reference by this UUID column.

Comment: It might be a bad idea to try to store the data twice (once in sqlite and once in Datastores)... you're going to have constant consistency issues. May I ask why you're doing that? Also, why would a user unlink and then relink the app? Is this really a problem you have to solve, or can you just document that this isn't supported?

Comment: @smarx Yes, saving data twice is a bad idea. Cloud syncing is an add-on feature for the app, so if a user did not enable Dropbox Datastore, data is saved locally. And user can turn on/off the syncing, which is link/unlink in the code. I feel this is a common task. Most of the apps I noticed using Dropbox APIs are simply using the Sync API at file level, like "Day One". Do you know any released app using the Datastore API? Maybe I can take a look at how they design the workflow.

Comment: So you're suggesting after enabling the Dropbox Datastore, I should migrate all the local SQLite data into Dropbox, and only have a single storage. That's reasonable, but Android has Content Provider and Cursor on top of SQLite, which tightly bind to CRUD operations and UI display. Replacing them with Dropbox stack is not trivial. Also after Dropbox unlinked, the app migrates the data back to SQLite. What should I do with the data left on the cloud? Wiping them out will affect other connected devices. Or leave them, then there are two copies, which will ultimately lead to sync conflict.

Comment: One thing we're considering on the Dropbox side is a way to use the Datastore API even with the user having a Dropbox account. (Obviously no syncing would happen... this would be purely local.) Would that solve your problem? Or would you still want to sync between datastores and sqlite to take advantage of Android's sqlite niceties? As for examples, I'd check out Diaro and see what they're doing.

Comment: I meant without, not with. :-)

Comment: @smarx Yeah, without user account would be nice. There is a library called ParcelKit for mirroring iOS CoreData and Dropbox Datastore. You can see people does not use Dropbox Datastore as a single storage solution, because there are a lot "niceties" offered by Android and iOS storage solutions.

Comment: @smarx Just want to get back to you, I did look into Diaro's sqlite schema, it helps a lot:) Thanks!

Comment: All strategies you've listed are valid, and there's no right way to go about it. I'm building something with datastore too, and this question has troubled me ALOT. However, the right thing is; as cliche as it sounds, "to set the user expectation right from the start". `Unlinking DB Account will Halt backup`. thats one. I'm looking for suggestions too, but I fear its unnecessary complexity trying to deal with datastore syncing associated with unlinking.

Comment: @user134611 You can take a look at Dirao's database schema, it helped a lot